# CruiseControl.NET Executable Task

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to run a exe from CruiseControl.NET as one of the task using web dashboard.
This exe is windows application, when I run this exe from command prompt it opens a window but when I run it from CruiseControl web dashboard it does not pop up window and it gets time out. I don't whether I can execute a windows application from CruiseControl web dashboard which in return opens a window, here is what I'm doing

```
  <exec>
    <executable>c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>C:\Builder\Builder.exe</buildArgs>
  </exec>
```

where Builder.exe is windows app which should open a popup window, but from CruiseControl.NET dashboard it does not come up? Is there any way to open windows app from CruiseControl web dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl.net is designed to run automatically from the command line. When you run the task from the web dashboard it will try to run it on the server as the IIS User, which may well not have permission to run, and even if it does will pop up on your build server in the IIS user account, not where you can see it or interact with it.

If you need to run a task during your CC.Net build process write it as a command line application.

Comment: As far as I know, the executables run by cc.net use the same user account as the cc.net service that is "Local System" by default. I prefer creating a separate account for the cc.net service. And I do agree that those executables must be able to work without any interaction with user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it really makes any sense. The documentation says: *"The Executable Task lets you invoke any command line executable (...) CCNet will examine the exit code when the executable ends and act accordingly. "* [Please see here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task)